# Shopify API PHP: Updating a variant's attributes, specifically inventory quantity

Tags: php, api, shopify

I'm using this PHP framework for use with [`Shopify's API`](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api)

Can anyone help me with updating a product's variant attributes, specifically the **inventory quantity**?

The corresponding api call as listed in the Shopify docs is:

```
/admin/variants/#{id}.json
```

To update a *product* attribute such as the title it's a case of:

```
$fields = array('title' => 'My New Product Edit');

$api->product->modify(89605609, $fields);
```

Changing these to reflect a variant doesn't work in the same way.

As always, any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library you are using is deprecated. You should use one of the libraries mentioned here: http://wiki.shopify.com/Shopify_App_Development#.E2.80.9CI.E2.80.99m_a_PHP_developer.E2.80.9D

Comment: Thanks, will use the current supported libraries

Comment: URL is out of date and Unsure of what to update it to. IE: https://help.shopify.com/en/search?q=App+Development&f=api

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following code and update variant values:

```
$product_array = array(
    'variant'=>array(               
    'id'=>#{id},
    'price'=>15.00
));

$put = $shopify('PUT /admin/variants/#{id}.json', array(), $product_array);
```

*(See the relevant [Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product-variant#update))*